# TypeScript Typings with createUseStyles from react-jss

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

I'm having a heck of a time getting my typings correct so I was curious if anyone had a working example or some feedback as to where I am going wrong. There are two things I need to happen with this instance of `createUseStyles`, accept the theme as well as props.

I took the example from the documentation website, and of course right off the bat its already throwing TypeScript errors, which is understandable:

(pasting screenshot just to show typescript errors)

[image]

code block from screenshot:

```
import React, { ReactNode, CSSProperties } from "react";
import {
  createUseStyles,
  useTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
  DefaultTheme,
  Styles
} from "react-jss";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  useRed: boolean;
}

interface PUTheme {
  colorPrimary: string;
  altColor: string;
}

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  button: {
    background: ({ theme }) => theme.colorPrimary
  },
  label: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

const Button2: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  console.log(theme);
  const classes = useStyles({ ...props, theme });
  return (
    <button className={classes.button}>
      <span className={classes.label}>{children}</span>
    </button>
  );
};

const theme = {
  colorPrimary: "green",
  altColor: "red"
};

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button2 useRed={true}>I am a button 2 with green background</Button2>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export default App;
```

The error found here **(Error 1)** is:

```
  button: {
    background: ({ theme }) => theme.colorPrimary
  },
```

> Property 'colorPrimary' does not exist on type 'Theme'.ts(2339)

Makes sense to an extent - it doesn't know what our theme consists of, so moving on...

The error found here **(Error 2)** for `theme` is:

```
const classes = useStyles({ ...props, theme });
```

> Type 'DefaultTheme' is not assignable to type 'Theme'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Theme'.ts(2322)

Right away.. I'm a little confused. But let's type some things and see how it works out...

Adding an interface for my theme doesn't seem to change any of the above errors:

```
interface PUTheme {
  colorPrimary: string;
  altColor: string;
}

const theme: PUTheme = {
  colorPrimary: "green",
  altColor: "red"
};
```

So since adding an interface to my theme object doesn't seem to accomplish much, I was able to satisfy the error from **Error 1** by adding typings. While this calms TypeScript down it feels, ***wrong?***

```
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  button: {
    background: ({ theme }: {theme: PUTheme}) => theme.colorPrimary
  },
  label: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});
```

However, this still leaves me with  **Error 2** except the error has changed *slightly*

> Type 'DefaultTheme' is not assignable to type 'PUTheme'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'PUTheme'

I've tried following back the typings in `react-jss` but perhaps this is over my head at the moment.

Does anyone have any tips or insight into what I'm doing wrong or working examples? Also, here is a link to my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-createusestyles-v1erw?file=/src/App.tsx) if you wish to see it in action.

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of images of your code.

Comment: I explained why it was a screenshot in the Question. It was to show where the errors were happening. The rest of the question are code blocks - which obviously are preferred. @LinuxServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I've found the solution. The passing of theme/props to the classes still feels strange to me but it works and satisfies TypeScript.

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { createUseStyles, useTheme, ThemeProvider } from "react-jss";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  useRed: boolean;
}

interface PUTheme {
  colorPrimary: string;
  altColor: string;
}

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  button: {
    background: ({
      theme,
      useRed
    }: {
      theme: PUTheme;
      useRed: Props["useRed"];
    }) => (useRed ? theme.altColor : theme.colorPrimary)
  },
  label: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

const Button2: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const theme = useTheme<PUTheme>();
  const classes = useStyles({ ...props, theme });
  return (
    <button className={classes.button}>
      <span className={classes.label}>{children}</span>
    </button>
  );
};

const theme: PUTheme = {
  colorPrimary: "green",
  altColor: "red"
};

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button2 useRed={true}>I am a button 2 with green background</Button2>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export default App;
```

The main thing I believe was missing was having `useTheme` typed `const theme = useTheme<PUTheme>();`

View working [Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-createusestyles-forked-hfhdt?file=/src/App.tsx)!

Answer (score 0):

You can try some incantations like this:

```
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  button: {
    background: (theme: PUTheme) => theme.colorPrimary
  },
  label: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

const Button2: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const theme = useTheme() as PUTheme;
  console.log(theme);
  const classes = useStyles(theme);
  return (
    <button className={classes.button}>
      <span className={classes.label}>{children}</span>
    </button>
  );
};
```

Note that it doesn't pass any `props` to `useStyles`. Looking at the type definition of this function it seems it can only accept a "`Theme`"